# Program keeps calling unexpected and terminate functions

Tags: c++, exception

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "otevector.h"
#include "poikkeus.h"

using namespace std;
using otecpp_otevector::OteVector;
using otecpp_poikkeus::asetaKasittelijat;
using otecpp_poikkeus::LaitonIndeksi;
using otecpp_poikkeus::OdottamatonPoikkeus;

namespace 
{
  void luoPoikkeus(OteVector<int> &t, int k) throw(LaitonIndeksi, OdottamatonPoikkeus) {
    if(k == 0) {
      t[4] = 10;   
    }
    else if(k == 1) {
      cout << t[-2]; 
    }
    else if(k == 2) {
      throw -500;     
    }
    else {
      throw 9.5;  
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  OteVector<int> t(4);
  asetaKasittelijat();  
  for(int kierros = 0; kierros < 4; ++kierros) {
    try {
      luoPoikkeus(t, kierros);
    }
    catch(LaitonIndeksi &li) {
    cout << li.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(OdottamatonPoikkeus &op) {
    cout << op.what() << '\n';
    }
  }
}


// Exception class (poikkeus.cpp)
#include <string>
#include "poikkeus.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using otecpp_poikkeus::LaitonIndeksi;
using otecpp_poikkeus::OdottamatonPoikkeus;
using namespace std;
namespace otecpp_poikkeus
{
    LaitonIndeksi::LaitonIndeksi(ptrdiff_t i)
    {
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Laiton indeksi: ";
        oss << i;
        this->merkkijono = oss.str();
        cout << this->merkkijono << endl;
    }
    const char* LaitonIndeksi::what() const throw()
    {
        return merkkijono.c_str();
    }
    OdottamatonPoikkeus::OdottamatonPoikkeus(const string &viesti)
    {
        this->merkkijono = "Odottamaton poikkeus: " + viesti;
    }
    const char* OdottamatonPoikkeus::what() const throw()
    {
        return merkkijono.c_str();
    }
    void asetaKasittelijat()
    {
    set_unexpected(odottamaton);
    set_terminate(terminatea);

    }
    void odottamaton()
    {
        try {
             throw;
        }catch (int i) {
          throw new LaitonIndeksi(i);
            } catch(const char* s) {
             cout << "string poikkeus: " << s;
         } catch (...) {
        cout << "Ohjelma lopetetaan odottamattoman poikkeuksen vuoksi" << endl; 
        terminate();
        }
    }
    void terminatea()
    {
        cout << "Kutsuttiin omaa terminate-funktiota";
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

}


 // Exception header (poikkeus.h)


#ifndef POIKKEUS_H
#define POIKKEUS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
namespace otecpp_poikkeus
{
    class LaitonIndeksi : public std::exception
    {
        std::string merkkijono;
    public:
        const char* what() const throw();
        LaitonIndeksi(ptrdiff_t i);
        ~LaitonIndeksi() throw() {}

    };
    class OdottamatonPoikkeus : public std::exception
    {
        std::string merkkijono;
    public:
        const char* what() const throw();
        OdottamatonPoikkeus(const std::string &viesti);
        ~OdottamatonPoikkeus() throw() { }

    };
    void asetaKasittelijat();
    void odottamaton();
    void terminatea();

}


#endif



//vector like class


#ifndef OTEVECTOR_H
#define OTEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include "poikkeus.h"
#include <exception>
using otecpp_poikkeus::LaitonIndeksi;
using otecpp_poikkeus::OdottamatonPoikkeus;
namespace otecpp_otevector {
    template<typename T>
    class OteVector
    {


    public:
        ptrdiff_t koko;
        T *taulu;

        OteVector(unsigned int koko);

        ~OteVector();
        T & operator[](ptrdiff_t i) throw(LaitonIndeksi);

        const T & operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const throw(LaitonIndeksi);

        OteVector(const OteVector<T> &v);

        OteVector<T>& operator=(const OteVector<T>& v);

    };
    template<typename T>
    OteVector<T>::OteVector(unsigned int koko)
    {
        this->koko = koko;
        this->taulu = new T[koko];
    }
    template<typename T>
    OteVector<T>::~OteVector()
    {
        delete[] taulu;
}
    template<typename T>
    T & OteVector<T>::operator[](ptrdiff_t i) throw(LaitonIndeksi)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i > this->koko - 1)
            {
             throw new LaitonIndeksi(i);
            }
           return taulu[i];

    }

    template<typename T>
    const T & OteVector<T>::operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const throw(LaitonIndeksi)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i > this->koko - 1)
            {
              throw new LaitonIndeksi(i);
            }
              return taulu[i];
        }
    template<typename T>
    OteVector<T>::OteVector(const OteVector<T> &v)
    {
        this->koko = v.koko;
        taulu = new T[v.koko];
        for (int i = 0; i < koko; i++)
        {
            this->taulu[i] = v.taulu[i];
        }
    }
    template<typename T>
    OteVector<T>& OteVector<T>::operator=(const OteVector<T>& v)
    {
        if (this->taulu == v.taulu) {
            return *this;
        }
        this->koko = v.koko;
        taulu = (new T[v.koko]);
        for (int i = 0; i < koko; i++)
        {
            this->taulu[i] = v.taulu[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
}
#endif // OTEVECTOR_H
```

Sorry about putting the whole code here but i have tried to find problem so long and i have no idea whats the problem. So problem is in main functions if(k== 0) (main is given me so i cant change that). When program calls [] operator of otevector class it doesn't write "LaitonIndeksi" message to console and it just moves to unexpected method(odottamaton()) and after that it just terminates program whit terminate method. Why these exceptions doesn't work and program just terminates?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger??

Comment: Hmm, haven't really because i'm pretty new whit programming. But i know that it goes to exceptions constructor and after that it just jumps somehow to unexpected method. So i guess i don't handle that exception or what?

Comment: Learning to use a debugger probably should be your next step in learning as they become invaluable in situations where you need to know where your code is failing or not behaving as expected. MSVC has a built in debugger within the ide otherwise I would recommend QT if you wanted to debug gnu generated binaries on windows. There are plenty of awesome options for graphical debuggers for linux that you wont have any trouble finding yourself.

Comment: Off topic: You gain nothing and lose a lot by separating a class definition from the method implementations when both are defined inside a header. The main reasons for separating the two is you can hide the implementation from sight and prevent unnecessary rebuilds. A template in a header has to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

The vector has 4 elements, with indices of 0, 1, 2, and 3. When `k` is 0, the code assigns a value to `t[4]`. That's not good.

Comment: Point of program is cause all these exceptions without ending the program. It's intentional.

Comment: @Laltzi out-of-bounds access using `[]` on a vector causes *undefined behaviour*. anything may happen. You cannot "catch" it and recover.

Comment: hmm that main was given me by teacher and i cant change it should work somehow whit that i ques. So i really cant handle that exception?

Comment: The `OteVector` `[]` operator tests for overrunning the buffer and throws an exception. The way it's thrown is not quite kosher, though. `throw new LaitonIndeksi(i);` will almost certainly result in a memory leak. Don't `new` the exception because odds are good no one will be there to `delete` it. At any rate, @Laltzi there is something to catch, you just have to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to write the code performing bound checking:

```
if (i < 0 || i > this->koko - 1)
{
    throw new LaitonIndeksi(i);
}
```

But you throw a pointer to exception, that is `LaitonIndeksi*`. The corresponding `catch` clause looks like:

```
catch (LaitonIndeksi &li) {
    cout << li.what() << '\n';
}
catch (OdottamatonPoikkeus &op) {
    cout << op.what() << '\n';
}
```

So `LaitonIndeksi*` gets unhandled, and unexpected handler is called.

What you should do is just throw the exception:

```
throw LaitonIndeksi(i);
```

Comment: Wow didn't knew that it works like that also whit exceptions that when i use new operator its going to be pointer. Thank you so much !